# Return ManyToManyField IDs when querying model in Django 2.1?

Tags: django, django-models, django-2.1

I have two very simple models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

class Event(models.Model):
    event_date = models.DateField()
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    people_involved = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person, blank=True, related_name="people_involved"
    )
```

I want to return all events, including the `people_involved`.

In views.py, I have the following:

```
def alljson(request):
    events = Event.objects.values()
    return JsonResponse(list(events), safe=False)
```

This returns:

```
[
    {
        "id": 9, 
        "event_date": "2019-01-01", 
        "short_description": "New Year's Party", 
    }, 
...
]
```

How do I include the `people_involved` ManyToManyField in this response?

Comment: You can add `people_involved` in your `values()` and you'll get the first one but still you won't have all of them. You can write more code to do so but i recommend to use Django Rest Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [model_to_dict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/forms/models/) like this:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

e_list = []
p_list = []
events = Event.objects.all()
for e in events:
    e_list.append(model_to_dict(e, fields=['event_date', 'short_description']))
    for p in e.people_involved.all():
        p_list.append(model_to_dict(p, fields=['full_name']))   
data = {'events': e_list, 'people_involved': p_list}
return JsonResponse(data)
```

with `model_to_dict` you an include or exclude a particular field if you want to :)

or

You can use [serializers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/serialization/) like this:

```
from django.core import serializers 

data = {}
events = Event.objects.all()
s_events = serializers.serialize("json", events)
data['events'] = s_events
for event in events:
    data['persons'] = serializers.serialize("json", event.people_involved.all())
return JsonResponse(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible way or i think is the best possible way to do that is to use `django-restframework-serlizers` [link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/).

If you don't want to use that, then unfortunately you need to manually generate all the response, there is no way to get them. You can do this like following

```
def alljson(request):
    events =[] 
    for event in Event.objects.values():
         response = {}
         response['id'] = event.id
         response['short_description'] = event.short_description
         response['event_date'] = event.event_date
         response['people_involved'] = list(event.people_involved.all())
         events.append(response)


    return JsonResponse(events, safe=False)
```