# How to iterate child data in nested for loop in relation to parent data for loop

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a for loop with a nested for loop. The parent for loop displays all the ingredients for the meal. Each ingredient has sub ingredients that I want to display under the "complete" ingredient.

Below is a general idea of the tables. I am not actually making an app related to food but this is just to simplify things.

***Meal* Table**

```
+---------+-----------------------+
| mMealID | mMealName             |
+---------+-----------------------+
| 0001    | English Big Breakfast |
+---------+-----------------------+
| ....    | ...                   |
+---------+-----------------------+
```

***Ingredient* Table**

```
+-----------------+-------------------+-----------+
| ingIngredientID | ingIngredientName | ingMealID |
+-----------------+-------------------+-----------+
| 0001            | Bacon             | 0001      |
+-----------------+-------------------+-----------+
| 0002            | Baked Beans       | 0001      |
+-----------------+-------------------+-----------+
| 0003            | Sausage           | 0001      |
+-----------------+-------------------+-----------+
| 0004            | Coffee            | 0001      |
+-----------------+-------------------+-----------+
| ....            | ...               | ....      |
+-----------------+-------------------+-----------+
```

***Sub Ingredient* Table**

```
+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+----------+
| siSubIngredientID | siSubIngredientName | siIngredientID | siMealID |
+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+----------+
| 0001              | Fat                 | 0001           | 0001     |
+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+----------+
| 0002              | Pork                | 0001           | 0001     |
+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+----------+
| 0003              | Salt                | 0001           | 0001     |
+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+----------+
| 0004              | Tomato Sauce        | 0002           | 0001     |
+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+----------+
| ....              | ...                 | ....           | ....     |
+-------------------+---------------------+----------------+----------+
```

**Desired Layout**

```
English Big Breakfast
    Bacon
        Fat
        Pork
        Salt
    Baked Beans
        Beans
        Tomato Sauce
    Sausage
        Pork
        Herbs
        Salt
    Coffee
        Coffee Beans
        Sugar
        Water
        Milk
    etc...
```

I can quite easily display ALL the sub ingredients under each complete ingredient however this is obviously what I don't want to happen. Because the nested loop will complete and exit back to the parent loop displaying all sub ingredients under each complete ingredient even if the sub ingredient isn't related to the parent. How would I write a query/loop that would only display the data that is related to the parent data? Or even any documentation I can look at to get on the write track.

Cheers for any and all help.

Some Django code if you need it:

**models.py**

```py
    class Meal(models.Model):
        mMealID = models.CharField(db_column='mMealID', max_length=10, primary_key=True)
        # ...

    class Ingredient(models.Model):
        ingMealID =models.ForeignKey('Meal', on_delete=models.PROTECT, db_column='ingMealID')
        ingIngredientID = models.DecimalField(db_column='IngredientID ', max_digits=4, decimal_places=0, primary_key=True)
        # ...

    class SubIngredient(models.Model):
        siMealID =models.ForeignKey('Meal', on_delete=models.PROTECT, db_column='siMealID ')
        siIngredientID = models.ForeignKey('Ingredient', on_delete=models.PROTECT, db_column='siIngredientID ')
        siSubIngredientID = models.IntegerField(db_column='subIngredient', primary_key=True)
        # ...
```

Sorry about the model/data structure, I am working with a legacy database (10+ years) that was designed by a child but it's what I have to deal with.

**template.html**

```py
    {% if mealQuery %}
    # ...
        {% for ingMealID in ingredientQuery %}
            <tr>
                ...
                <td>{{ ingMealID.ingredientID }}</td>
                ...
            </tr>
            {% for siMealID in subIngredientQuery %}
                <tr>
                    ...
                    <td>{{ siMealID.siSubIngredientID }}</td>
                    ...
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    # ...
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `SubIngredient` have ForeignKey to `Ingredient` class instead of `Meal` ?

Comment: @Ahtisham `SubIngredient` has a foreign key to both `Meal` and `Ingredient`.

Comment: Perhaps are looking for Django SubQueries, that's one of its main applications.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda From what I can tell a SubQuery is used for one specific query however I need this query to work over an undefined amount of iterations. So 1 Meal, n Ingredients, n sub-ingredients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) like this:

views.py:

```
from .models import Meal
from django.shortcuts import render

def your_vew(request):
   meals = Meal.objects.all() 
   return render(request, 'your_html.html', {'meals': meals})
```

your_html:

```
{% for meal in meals %} 
   <p> {{ meal.mMealID }} </p>
   {% for in_meal in meal.ingredient_set.all %} 
      <p style="padding-left:20px;"> {{ in_meal.ingIngredientName }} </p>
      {% for sub_in in in_meal.subingredient_set.all %}
         <p style="padding-left:60px;"> {{ sub_in.siSubIngredientName }} </p> 
      {% endfor %} 
   {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @Moms Edited my answer so that it exactly relates to your desired layout :)

Comment: Thank you for the help! I believe this is on the right track. I should mention that I do not need a for loop for the Meal itself. That is specified by the user input `meals = Meal.objects.filter(mMealID=id)`. However I am not getting any data out of `{% for in_meal in meal.ingredient_set.all %}` I am still playing around with it but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Moms :) check if meals in `meals = Meal.objects.filter(mMealID=id)` is not giving you `None`. Also check if `instance/object` has any igredients associated with it.

Comment: the parent for loop is displaying data correctly however the child for loop isn't showing anything. I am fairly new to Django, Is there any way to dump all the data that queryset contains? similar to php's `vardump()`?

Comment: @Moms Yes there is. You can refer to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54555815/return-manytomanyfield-ids-when-querying-model-in-django-2-1/54557054#54557054

Comment: You didn't answer my question does meals that you are displaying have igredients objects associated with them ?

Comment: The Meals and the Ingredients Objects are displaying fine. It is the sub ingredients that aren't showing.

Comment: Does that even have sub-ingredients created ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188088/discussion-between-moms-and-ahtisham).